# How to make your script easy to keep track with?

Tags: javascript

I know this question is going to be...weird and...odd. I have programmed stuffs for around 4 years until now, since I was 14. I found out that I have changed my ways of writing script quite many times and I don't know which way is better, is there any standard for writing and displaying a script?

Ok, this is how I write when I started [I will make an example with long, deep [whatever] so you can see how I display a script]:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
odd=0; even=0;
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
for(j=0; j<10; j++)
{
if((i+j)%2==0)
{
even++;
alert(i+j);
}
else
{
odd++;
alert(i+j);
}
}
}
});
```

And then, when I started some more complex script, I found out that the way above is completely stupid, so I changed several times the way to write it, and about 2 years ago, I found out a way to write script for myself:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    odd=0; even=0;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
        for(j=0; j<10; j++)
            {
            if((i+j)%2==0)
                {
                even++;
                alert(i+j);
                }
            else
                {
                odd++;
                alert(i+j);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Well, it looks more clearly right? But recently, I found out that many programmers write script in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    odd = 0;
    even = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                even++;
                alert(i + j);
            }
            else {
                odd++;
                alert(i + j);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And I am confused now. I want to have myself a way that will last forever. So I am asking if there is any standard of how to display your script so that it will be easy to keep track of for everyone else?

Thanks for any idea. :P
[x]

Comment: Hopefully, regardless of the indentation and bracing style you use, you don't actually write scripts without declaring your variables. All of the scripts in your question run afoul of the **[Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)**

Comment: IMHO, the transition between 1, 2 and 3 is clear improvement, but that's only because I like my braces on line ends, and 4 char tabulation. Though I would put `} else {` on a single line. People fight over these tings endlessly, so to certain extent this is comparable to religion. The best metrics for a good code style, IMO, is the time it takes to understand what the code does by looking at its source. Indentation, empty lines, single line statements all help.

Comment: Bracing and indentation style are subjective. What you think is great, I think is terrible, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but that means there is no standard for displaying a script right? So I just have to pick a way that I like.
And @Pawel Veselov: I love that `} else {` too, I've seen them alot, but I don't know if it is a standard or not. Now I have a clue, I will try to find myself my own way. [x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two ways you show are quite literally religious totems for two opposing camps. You will find people on both sides vigorously supporting their style. Don't get sucked into the fight. Use whichever you like, be consistent, and don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, now I know that, there is no standard in displaying it, that means someone who develops my script later on will have to figure out it him/her self.
[x]

Answer (score 1):

Take your first script, enter it into http://jsbeautifier.org/ and click "Beautify" and you'll see that it turns out like your last script, so I think your last version is a style that you can stick with.

However, notice the dropdowns on the right allow for 2 space indents (what I prefer) and other options, so you'll find that different developers prefer slightly different variations.  In fact, if your boss prefers one variation and is a stickler, you'll have to change your own preference anyway.  The key point is to write code that is easily decipherable at a glance.

Comment: Great tool! Thank you alot. I hope that I could follow that style! [x]